Troubles with simulation nodes. (Shaders not preserved, attributes not working)

I'm trying to make a simple smoke effect using geometry nodes I have a set up where I have a loop that creates 5 instances of smoke particles. I try to attach two attributes (ParticleAge) and (ParticleVelocity) to the instances. I have it attached to a simulation so 5 instances of smoke particle is created every frame. Each frame the age of each instance is incremented and its position and velocity is changed to go in an upward motion with some random added velocity to sell the illusion but instead each frame the ball of smoke particles don't end up moving and then overlap in a ball of new instances of smoke particle. I think this has something to do with the attributes not working because if I disconnect the velocity attribute and manually input an upwards movement the stream of smoke moves up but not with the velocity. And before I had the 5 instance generator, I could generate a singular instance and the physics would work properly. The second issue I'm having is that shaders that are applied before the simulation node seems to be erased while node groups applied after the simulation don't end up getting applied. The node groups for me only work before the simulation and the shaders only work after and I don't know why.

Side Note: Beware that the provided picture is unreadable...

I was able to fix the instance part myself, I had to create a point each iteration of the repeat and convert that point into an instance, just plugging in an object geometry alone does not work.
I also figured out that instances have trouble applying added modifiers after the simulation, so use the Realize Instance node to convert the instance into "usable" geometry.
